# How to remove Spark values that are out of sequence

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to remove some values from dataframe that is not in right place.

I have the following dataframe, for example:

```
+-----+-----+
|count|PHASE|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    3|
|    2|    3|
|    3|    6|
|    4|    6|
|    5|    8|
|    6|    4|
|    7|    4|
|    8|    4|
+-----+-----+
```

I need to remove 6 and 8 from dataframe because of some rules:

```
phase === 3 and lastPhase.isNull
phase === 4 and lastPhase.isin(2, 3)
phase === 6 and lastPhase.isin(4, 5)
phase === 8 and lastPhase.isin(6, 7)
```

This is a huge dataframe and those misplaced values can happen many times.
Could you help with that, please?

Expected output:

```
+-----+-----+------+
|count|PHASE|CHANGE|
+-----+-----+------+
|    1|    3|     3|
|    2|    3|     3|
|    3|    6|     3|
|    4|    6|     3|
|    5|    8|     3|
|    6|    4|     4|
|    7|    4|     4|
|    8|    4|     4|
+-----+-----+------+
```

```
   val rows = Seq(
      Row(1, 3),
      Row(2, 3),
      Row(3, 6),
      Row(4, 6),
      Row(5, 8),
      Row(6, 4),
      Row(7, 4),
      Row(8, 4)
    )
    val schema = StructType(
      Seq(StructField("count", IntegerType), StructField("PHASE", IntegerType))
    )
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows),
      schema
    )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you want to populate column *CHANGE* as follow:

> For a dataframe sorted by *count* column, for each row, if the value of the *PHASE* column matches a defined set of rules, set this value in *CHANGE* column. If value doesn't match the rules, set latest valid *PHASE* value in *CHANGE* column

To do so, **You can use an [user-defined aggregate function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html) to setup *CHANGE* column over a [window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) ordered by *COUNT* column**

First, you define an `Aggregator` object where its buffer will be the last valid phase, and you implement your set of rules in its `reduce` function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

object LatestValidPhase extends Aggregator[Integer, Integer, Integer] {

  def zero: Integer = null

  def reduce(lastPhase: Integer, phase: Integer): Integer = {
    if (lastPhase == null && phase == 3) {
      phase
    } else if (Set(2, 3).contains(lastPhase) && phase == 4) {
      phase
    } else if (Set(4, 5).contains(lastPhase) && phase == 6) {
      phase
    } else if (Set(6, 7).contains(lastPhase) && phase == 8) {
      phase
    } else {
      lastPhase
    }
  }

  def merge(b1: Integer, b2: Integer): Integer = {
    throw new NotImplementedError("should not use as general aggregation")
  }

  def finish(reduction: Integer): Integer = reduction

  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Integer] = Encoders.INT

  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Integer] = Encoders.INT

}
```

Then you transform it into an aggregate user-defined function that you apply over your window ordered by *COUNT* column:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udaf}

val latest_valid_phase = udaf(LatestValidPhase)
val window = Window.orderBy("count")

df.withColumn("CHANGE", latest_valid_phase(col("PHASE")).over(window))
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I needed to bump spark version in order to try your solution! I really appreciated that! Do I need to have any concerns about performance using UDAF?

Comment: UDAFs will always be slower than Spark's built-in aggregate functions. But I don't see how to solve your question with only Spark's built-in functions. I didn't benchmark this specific UDAF so I don't know. I don't think you should have concerns about performance. However, If you want to be sure, test it on the whole dataset and see if you're satisfied with its performance.